# Explicit cast explanation in terms of memory for reference type in C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, casting, reference

In MSDN, "For **reference types**, an explicit cast is required if you need to convert from a base type to a derived type".

In wiki, "In programming language theory, a **reference type is a data type that refers to an object in memory**. A pointer type on the other hand refers to a memory address. Reference types can be thought of as pointers that are implicitly dereferenced." which is the case in C.

How to explain the memory storing procedure when considering explicit casting for reference type in C#?

Comment: The object is stored in the memory independenty from the references to the object. Casting is used to obtain a reference that treats the object as a specific type.

[From the same MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx):

"A cast operation between reference types does not change the run-time type of the underlying object; it only changes the type of the value that is being used as a reference to that object."

Comment: the question discusses `C#`, so the tags `C` and `C++` should be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most cases, there's really not much conceivable difference between a reference variable and a pointer variable. Both point to a location in memory. The type of the reference (or pointer) variable tells the compiller which operations can be performed using it.

Instead of C pointers, which are (primarily) used with basic types (such as int or byte), consider C++ object pointers first. It's really almost the same as in C#:

```
MyBaseClass* a = new MyBaseclass();
a->BaseMethod(); // Call method using -> operator (dereference and call)

MyBaseClass* b = new MyDerivedClass();
b->DerivedMethod(); // Error: MyBaseClass has no such method

// Proper C++-Style casting. 
MyDerivedClass* c = dynamic_cast<MyDerivedClass*>(b);
// Shortcut to the above, does not do the type test. 
// MyDerivedClass* c = (MyDerivedClass*)b; 
c->DerivedMethod(); // Ok
```

This translates almost 1:1 to C#, so reference types are (from a programmer point of view) just pointers with a defined type. The only visible difference would be that a direct C-Style cast in C# is equivalent to a try_cast in C++, which will ensure that you can never assign a wrong target instance to a reference variable.

So the differences between a reference type and a pointer to an object are (most of these are implied by the fact that C# is a managed language):

- A reference variable can never point to invalid memory (except to NULL).
- A reference variable can never point to an object that's not of its type.
- When assigning a value to a reference variable, the type is always tested.
- A cast on a reference variable needs to check that the target object is of the given type.

Answer (score 2):

The reference objects are stored on a heap, where they can be referenced from the code. The object, as it is on the heap, is of a given type.

From the code, you can create references to it, and those references can be cast to some some other types.

Now, there are couple of cases, which are described in the referenced article. I will use the examples from there to make it easier.

**1. Implicit conversions**

Implicit conversion takes place, when you don't ask for it specifically in code. Compiler has to know by itself how to do this.

**1.1. Value Types**

If the type of value that you are trying to cast is of size, that allows you to store it in the size of memory that makes the size of the type you want to cast to, then compiler will let you do that. This is mostly for numeric values, so following the examples from your referenced article:

```
// Implicit conversion. num long can
// hold any value an int can hold, and more!
int num = 2147483647;
long bigNum = num;
```

So since int is 'smaller' than long, compiler will let you do this.

**1.2. Reference Types**

Assuming you have following classes definitions:

```
class Base {    

}

class Derived : Base {
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    public int CalculateSomething ()
    {
         return IntProperty * 23;
    }
}
```

Then you can safely do conversions like:

```
Derived d = new Derived();
Base b = d;
```

This is because object d, which you have created on the heap, is of type `Derived`, and since it's a derived type from type `Base`, it is guaranteed to have all members that `Base` has. So it's safe to convert the reference and use `Derived` object as `Base` object. Because **Derived IS Base** (`Derived : Base`).

**2. Explicit conversions**

Let's assume we have another class in our project:

```
class DerivedLike
{
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
    public int CalculateSomethingElse()
    {
        return IntProp * 23;
    }
}
```

If we write

```
DerivedLike dl = new DerivedLike();
Derived d = dl;
```

we'll get from our compiler that it cannot implicitly convert type `DerivedLike` to `Derived`.

This is, because the two reference types are totally different, so compiler cannot allow you to do that. Those types have different properties and methods.

**2.1. Implementing explicit conversion**

As long as you cannot convert from Derived class to Base class by yourself, you can write an operator in most other cases.

If one wants to proceed with conversion from DerivedLike to Derived, we must implement in the `DerivedLike` class, a conversion operator. It's a static operator which tells how to convert one type to another. The conversion operator may be either implicit, or explicit. Explicit will require the developer to cast it explicitly, by providing the Type name in the parenthesis.

The recommendation for choosing between implicit and explicit operators is that if conversion may throw exceptions, it should be explicit, so that conversion is done consciously by the developer.

Let's change our code to meet that requirement:

```
class DerivedLike
{
    public static explicit operator Derived(DerivedLike a)
    {
        return new Derived() { IntProperty = a.IntProp};
    }
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
    public int CalculateSomethingElse()
    {
        return IntProp * 23;
    }
}
```

So this will compile fine now:

```
DerivedLike dl = new DerivedLike();
Derived d = (Derived)dl;
```

Going back to memory topic, please note, that with such conversion, you will now have two objects on the heap.

One created here:

```
DerivedLike dl = new DerivedLike();
```

Second one created here:

```
Derived d = (Derived)dl;
```

The object on the heap cannot change it's type.

Hope this clarifies.